# Can a method use an automatic variable to infer the return type?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

```
IDictionary<int,string> myMethod()
{
 var returnVal = ...;

 return returnVal;
}
```

It seems like this is something that should be possible - create a var which automatically takes the method's return type - but I can't find any keyword which would match this. Does it exist?

Comment: "Does it exist?" Nope.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an object the way you're trying to will not work. A variable's type is determined when it is declared - the compiler doesn't care how you use it (for the most part). So, just because you return it doesn't mean the compiler will automatically infer what the initial type is.

Wjdavis15's answer (which has apparently now been deleted - it made use of generics and initializing the return value to `default(T)`) kinda sorta works, but it's very limited. It works fine for value types, but reference types the variable will be initialized to null... which is pretty useless unless you're planning on returning null to begin with. Instead, you might be able to do something like so:

```
private T MyMethod<T>() where T : new()
{
    var retVal = new T();
    ...
    return retVal;
}

// Use the method like so:
var dict = MyMethod<IDictionary<int,string>>();
```

This will work as long as T has a parameterless constructor. The problem with this, of course, is that the method is generic, meaning that it can be used with any class type, not just the one specific class you had in mind. You'd be better off using a non-generic method.

In summary, no, the feature you describe doesn't exist in C#. There are workarounds that are similar to what you want to do, but using them in the way you want is cumbersome and confusing, so it's better you just define what the variable is in the declaration.

Comment: It seems like the real answer is simply "no" - I had wondered if there was some special `ReturnType` auto type as I'm sure I saw in some language or other.

Comment: @Mr.Boy I posted an answer providing a solution that infers a local variable to the return type of the method, so clearly the answer *isn't* "no".

Comment: Your solution requires me to change the method signature though, so while it's a technically interesting thing I think "not really but here is an intersting way you can force it" is more accurate - it's akin to using reflection to look up the method return type and then instance an object; not practical but theoretically possible!

Answer (score -1):

If you call the method recursively then you can have a local variable that infers the type of that method's return value.

```
public static int Foo()
{
    var bar = Foo();
    return bar;
}
```

Of course, it forces you to call the method recursively to do so.

Comment: Oh boy this gave me a good chuckle at first. But on a second thought this actually does what @Mr. Boy wants. Although I'd never recommend this

Comment: @stt106 You could make it not loop infinitely, just like you would for any other recursive method; this is purely demonstrating the point that you can infer a local variable to the return type of the method.